# jenkins svn run as root

Tags: linux, svn, jenkins

I'm new to jenkins.

I got jenkins intalled with

```
...
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

on a linux system.

I've got a project(s) with svn checkout.

[image]

Every time when jenkins checkout the svn-repo, the files ownership get root ownership ( root / root ).

But the jenkins is not an root user.

In some projects it make "mvn clean" impossible, or delete a folder.

I google about it

> svn checkout as root

can do this.

I think about it, that i will run jenkins (service) as another user.

Manualy i set the workspace folder in jenkins to jenkins user / group.
But in some project after svn update is get back to "root / root" ownership.

I don't know the real reason for "svn as root".
I look for the answer, and I would appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

It is very, very unlikely the checkout would create files owned by root if Jenkins was not running as root. Practically the only explanation is that Jenkins really running as root and you did not check it from a reliable source. The user which Jenkins reports under $JENKINS_URL/systemInfo might be wrong. (How did you check Jenkins is not running as root?)

Please check again by running something like

```
ps axu | grep java
```

or

```
top
```

and look for the java process and see who is the user running it.

How exactly to fix your installation depends how you installed Jenkins. Please provide more information if you need more help.

Comment: top: 20810 jenkins   20   0 1355m  48m  12m S    0  0.6   0:07.48 java

Comment: ps : jenkins  20810  0.2  0.6 1387936 49944 ?       Sl   11:12   0:07 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -cp /var/cache/jen..